# Android preferenceScreen color

Tags: android, android-listview, android-preferences, android-theme

I want a custom preference screen.

I can set the background color of the `ListView` and the padding at the right and left. But how can I chance the color of the borders, which are marked red in my screenshot?

[image: preference screen]

My example preferences file (preferences.xml)

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory
                    android:title="@string/pref_category"
                    android:key="catConnection">
            <CheckBoxPreference
                    android:title="@string/pref_warning_title"
                    android:summary="@string/pref_warning_desc"
                    android:defaultValue="true"
                    android:key="warning"
                    />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

As you can see, it's a normal preference file.

It would be nice if someone could post a screenshot and working style file.

Comment: use custom image as background...

Comment: Do you mean, I should set **android:background**?

Comment: ya that could be your option... put color or image as background for layout...

Comment: If I set to a color, the edges left and right are in this color. That's what I mean in my original post. But the real **border** (around my `ListView`) doesn't chance.

Comment: yes, use android:background and android:padding to your base layout. don't use margins.

Comment: if you want working style, please post your layout files.

Comment: @Prag's No idea? It's not as easy as you thought...